# Why didn’t Neri go to Planet of the Oceans?

Tags: ocean-girl

As per the last episode of the 2nd season, Myra was going to her planet. Neri comes with her to go there also. But at the last minute, she changed her mind, Neri staying on Earth. Does anyone have an idea why Neri changed her mind? Is it the for the reasons below?

1. Fathers Mission + Jali + Jason
2. Jali + Jason + Fathers Mission
3. Jason + Fathers Mission + Jali

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Season 2, Episode 13:

> **Neri**: I will miss my sister. Mera wishes in her heart to return home.
>   I know the day will come when I will see her again.
>
> **Jason**:    We really thought you’d gone too.
>
> **Brett**:    Yeah.
>
> **Neri**: Your people will live in the seas. Maybe one day they even talk
>   to Charley. I must stay to finish Father’s work. Mera will take hope
>   to our own people. She will be where she belongs. I belong here. My
>   island, the ocean, and with you. Family. Charley!
>
> **Brett**:    Go for it.

- She stayed for her friends, i.e. her adoptive family, including (and in light of events of later seasons, especially) Jason.
- She didn't stay for the whales (*jali*), but for one whale in particular, for Charley.
- Yes, she also stayed for her father's mission. That's why she says she "must finish Father's work."

It seems that you also want rankings of her reasons for staying. I can't say for sure, since there is no clear indication in the show. What I can say is that Neri has always been shown to value individuals, whether human or animal,  over ideals, and her friends most highly. I therefore suspect that finishing her father's work is secondary to being with her friends, such as Jason and Charley. Given that she later fell in love with Jason,  it seems likely the ranking is:

1. Jason
2. Charley, other *jali*, and other human friends.
3. Her father's work.